# C Basic Phonebook app will not display phone numbers in proper format

Tags: c, formatting

I have here a basic phonebook app written in C and the goal is to display the phone numbers entered in "1234567890" format in this "(123)-456-7890 format when 1 is selected and the phonebook entries are displayed. At the moment however, it isn't displaying them in this format. (and the phone numbers displayed aren't even the ones entered??) I'm not sure how to fix these problems, some help would be appreciated. Please tell me exactly what to enter where as merely telling me what is wrong probably won't help me correct the problem (I wouldn't know how). Thank you so much in advance!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

struct PhoneBook_Contacts
{
    char FirstName[20]; //Entered First Name
    char LastName[20]; //Entered Last Name
  long unsigned PhoneNumber[20]; //Phone Number
}; //TypeDef to Modify structure name

void decompose(long unsigned number, int* area, int* prefix, int* lineno) {
  *area = (number / (10000000));
  *prefix = ((number % (10000000) / 10000));
  *lineno = (number % (10000));
}

//Begin main function
int main(void)
{
    int area, prefix, lineno;
    int counter = 0; 
    int iSelection = 0; //Variable to use to select menu choice//Global counter variable used to keep track of number of contacts
                     //phone *phonebook; //Phonebook instance
                     //phonebook = (phone*)malloc(sizeof(phone) * 1); //Allocate memory for contacts
    struct PhoneBook_Contacts phonebook[3];



    printf("---=== Phone Numbers ===---\n\n");


    while (iSelection <= 4)
    {

        printf("1. Display Phone List\n");
        printf("2. Add a Number\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &iSelection);
        printf("\n");

        // Add Friend
        if (iSelection == 2)
        {
            if (counter == 3) {
                printf("ERROR!!! Phone Number List is Full\n");
                printf("\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("Add a Number\n");
                printf("============\n");
                scanf("%lu", phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
                printf("\n");
                counter++;
            }
        } //End if
          //printf("%d\n", iSelection);
          //Print Phonebook Entries
        if (iSelection == 1)
        {
            int x = 0;
            printf("Phone Numbers\n");
            printf("==============\n");
            for (x = 0; x < counter; x++) //For loop to print entries
            {
          decompose(*phonebook[x].PhoneNumber, &area, &prefix, &lineno);
                printf("%lu\n", *phonebook[x].PhoneNumber); //Contact's Phone Number
                printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
                printf("\n");
            }
            //printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
            //printf("\n");

            //End for loop
        } //End if

          //Exit Application
        if (iSelection == 0)
        {
            printf("Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!\n");
            break;
        } //End if

    } //End while
    return 0;
} //End main function
```

Answer (score 1):

`long unsigned PhoneNumber[20]` and `*phonebook[x].PhoneNumber` are nonsense;  I don't see you ever indexing `PhoneNumber`, so you probably never intended it to be an array of 20 unsigned longs, capable of storing up to 20 phone numbers per person.  So, it should be `unsigned long PhoneNumber`.

Comment: I attempted to replay long unsigned PhoneNumber[20] with your suggested unsigned long PhoneNumber, but it gave a compilation error asking for a pointer...not sure how to fix that

Comment: I would be willing to bet that the compilation error was issued on a very specific line, corresponding to a very specific statement, right?  Would you like to share which statement that was?

Comment: With `scanf()` you always have to take the address of the variables you want to scan, like this: `scanf("%lu", &phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);`

Answer (score 1):

Change `printf("%d%d%d\n", area, prefix, lineno);`
To:    `printf("(%d)-%d-%d\n", area, prefix, lineno);`

Note: you have other errors in your code, but this answers your formating question.

Comment: Thank you, this did fix the formatting for the phone number display!! I knew I probably had other errors but no clue what they are unfortunately. Now I just have to fix one more problem - the phone numbers aren't appearing correctly. For example: I enter the following three numbers:
4164915050
9052301212
6475551212
and it displays like this:
(416)-491-5050
(46)-236-6620
(218)-58-3916

No clue where its getting these numbers from...only the first number appears correctly. How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

The OP has ask for max assistance so:

The following code:

1. properly checks for errors
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the desired operations
4. appropriately separates code blocks
5. appropriately separates functions
6. does not have any 'magic' numbers
7. has only been lightly tested

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3
#define MAX_FIRSTNAME_LEN  20
#define MAX_LASTNAME_LEN   20
#define MAX_PHONE_LEN      20

struct PhoneBook_Contacts
{
    char FirstName[ MAX_FIRSTNAME_LEN+1 ]; //Entered First Name
    char LastName[ MAX_LASTNAME_LEN+1 ]; //Entered Last Name
    char PhoneNumber[ MAX_PHONE_LEN+1 ]; //Phone Number, format aaapppdddd
};



void decompose(      struct PhoneBook_Contacts * );
void AddFriend(      struct PhoneBook_Contacts *, size_t * );
void DisplayFriends( struct PhoneBook_Contacts *, size_t  );


//Begin main function
int main(void)
{
    struct PhoneBook_Contacts phonebook[ SIZE ];
    size_t counter = 0;
    size_t iSelection = 4; // menu selection, init to invalid value


    printf("---=== Phone Numbers ===---\n\n");

    while( 0 != iSelection )
    {
        printf( "1. Display Phone List\n"
                "2. Add a Number\n"
                "0. Exit\n\n"
                "Please select from the above options: ");

        if( 1 != scanf("%lu", &iSelection) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for menu selection failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        puts( "" );

        switch( iSelection )
        {
            case 0:
                // Exit Application
                printf("Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!\n");
                break;

            case 1:
                DisplayFriends( &phonebook[0], counter );
                break;

            case 2:
                AddFriend( &phonebook[0], &counter );
                break;

            default:
                puts( "invalid input" );
                break;
        } // end switch()
    } //End while
    return 0;
} //End main function


void decompose( struct PhoneBook_Contacts *phonebook )
{
    // note: assume phone number contains 9 characters ( aaapppdddd )

    char digits[5] = {phonebook->PhoneNumber[6],
                      phonebook->PhoneNumber[7],
                      phonebook->PhoneNumber[8],
                      phonebook->PhoneNumber[9],
                      '\0' };

    char prefix[4] = {phonebook->PhoneNumber[3],
                      phonebook->PhoneNumber[4],
                      phonebook->PhoneNumber[5],
                      '\0' };

    char area[4]   = {phonebook->PhoneNumber[0],
                      phonebook->PhoneNumber[1],
                      phonebook->PhoneNumber[2],
                      '\0' };

    printf( "1-(%3s) %3s-%4s\n", area, prefix, digits );
} // end function: decompose


void AddFriend(  struct PhoneBook_Contacts *phonebook, size_t *counter )
{
    if ( SIZE == *counter )
    {
        printf("ERROR!!! Phone Number List is Full\n\n");
    }

    else
    {
        puts("Add a Number");
        puts("============");

        puts( "Enter phone number (##########)" );
        //if( 1 != scanf("%" MAX_PHONE_LEN "s", phonebook[counter]->PhoneNumber) )
        if( 1 != scanf("%20s", phonebook[*counter].PhoneNumber) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for phone number failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        puts( "Enter first name" );
        //if( 1 != scanf("%" MAX_FIRSTNAME_LEN "s", phonebook[counter]->FirstName) )
        if( 1 != scanf("%20s", phonebook[*counter].FirstName) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for first name failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        puts( "Enter last name" );
        //if( 1 != scanf("%" MAX_LASTNAME_LEN "s", phonebook[counter]->LastName) )
        if( 1 != scanf("%20s", phonebook[*counter].LastName) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for last name failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        puts("");

        (*counter)++;
    } // end if
} // end function: AddFriend


void DisplayFriends( struct PhoneBook_Contacts *phonebook, size_t counter )
{
    puts("Phone Numbers");
    puts("==============");

    if( 0 == counter )
    {
        puts( "phone book empty" );
    }

    else
    {
        for ( size_t x = 0; x < counter; x++) //For loop to print entries
        {
            puts( phonebook[x].FirstName );
            puts( phonebook[x].LastName );
            decompose( &phonebook[x] );
        }
    }

    puts("");
} // end function: DisplayFriends
```

here is a sample run of the code

```
---=== Phone Numbers ===---

1. Display Phone List
2. Add a Number
0. Exit

Please select from the above options: 1

Phone Numbers
==============
phone book empty

1. Display Phone List
2. Add a Number
0. Exit

Please select from the above options: 2

Add a Number
============
Enter phone number (##########)
1234567890
Enter first name
george
Enter last name
harry

1. Display Phone List
2. Add a Number
0. Exit

Please select from the above options: 1

Phone Numbers
==============
george
harry
1-(123) 456-7890

1. Display Phone List
2. Add a Number
0. Exit

Please select from the above options: 0

Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!
```